# Twisted server-client interconnecting XML-RPC and REST services

Tags: python, twisted, xml-rpc, python-requests

I have a service provided by a REST API, with a Python library wrapping it using python-requests.

I have a 'dumb' user interface designed by a third party (not Python) to connect to a local XML-RPC.

Now I have to connect both ends and forward the XML-RPC calls to the REST API and return the results. It's mostly asynchronous and doesn't depend on results returning to the user in real-time. Most of the XML-RPC calls are supposed to return immediately, queue a task, and some other call will query the results later. Data is stored in an sqlite database until needed.

So, I decided to use twisted.web.xmlrpc for this middle layer and use the requests based lib for the remote calls and it works fine. I guess I'm blocking twisted's mainloop for a few seconds once in a while, but that's not a big deal.

The problem is that I also have to make some big file uploads from this middle layer to the  HTTP server providing the REST API. I can't make those uploads using the requests based lib because it will block the twisted loop until the upload is finished.

I'd rather not use multithreading, and I really don't want to rewrite the python-requests based lib I have as a twisted client. Is there any way I can integrate requests into twisted's mainloop, or any other reasonable solution?

Comment: "How do I fix my code without changing it?"  That's a tough one.  Most fixes involve at least some changes.

Comment: Sorry to have bothered you.  I'll try to steer clear of your questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like requests' style of API, but want something that would work with Twisted, consider using [treq](https://github.com/dreid/treq).  There are [support libraries](https://launchpad.net/synchronous-deferred) for writing interfaces which can be either synchronous or asynchronous depending on their caller's needs.

If you really want to use requests, but you don't want to block the main loop, you can invoke it with [`twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread.html).  This is mostly transparent, and if your requests don't share any state you can almost ignore the fact that you're using multithreading.

But, ultimately, Jean-Paul's comment is correct; you are going to need to make some changes to the way this code works, if you want to change the way it works.

Comment: This was a few months ago, and in the end I used deferToThread as you suggest.